# "I didn't hear back from you about [something]" - Correct use?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, email

This is my first post.

**Background**: I applied for further studies, to one of collaborators lab and he replied with a very positive e-mail, asking about time to talk on phone. But after that I never received e-mail from him, so I am following up.

I am starting my response like this:

> I am sure you are very busy, but I didn’t hear back from you about the
>   convenient time to further discuss xxx position in your lab.

But I am not sure if:
**1)** I can add "about ...." after "I didn't hear back from you"? and
**2)** if its rude to mention that I haven't heard from you?

Your responses will help me use "didn't hear" correctly in future.

Bade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's rude to mention not hearing back from someone. I do it all the time. Your wording looks fine to me (I'm not nitpicky)—but I would also mention (ask) if perhaps he didn't receive *your* email and that's why he hadn't responded. Emails get lost in cyberspace all the time.

You didn't specify if you sent an email response to him regarding the phone call scheduling. Assuming you *did* respond and are waiting to hear back, then what you're doing is not rude. It *might* be considered rude if you *hadn't* responded, as he is probably waiting for you to email him. If that is the case, you should apologize for the misunderstanding and move forward from there. It might be a little awkward, but not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

You used **about** correctly.

**About** + what you referred, and the topic which is being discussed.

Related to your answer, since he hasn't been in touch with you, and you haven't received any response back, **present perfect** would be more proper:

> I am sure you are very busy, but I haven't heard back from you about the convenient time to further discuss xxx position in your lab.

In order to make you letter sound more formal (I presume it is a formal letter), I would rewrite the beginning of the clause:

> You, being a business man, must a very busy person, nevertheless..

Comment: the first time I have read your answer, I liked it, however I ave done more researches and found out it is not the best thing to be said, check out this  [I Know You’re Busy But…](http://successfulculture.com/i-know-youre-busy-but/)